# Combining several features into one single feature

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I would like to know what might be the side effects of combining several features into one single feature for classification tasks. Imagine I have two variables with the following domains:

- A is binary (in {0,1})
- B are integers
- C in [0, 1)

We could feed the classifier with tuples (a, b, c), or we can represent the three features using one real number: the variable A can be expressed with the sign of the number, the integer part is B and the decimal part is C:

```
X = (B + C) * (1 if A == 0 else -1)
```

It seems this seems like a good idea to reduce the number of dimensions of the space, but what are the dis/advantages of using X instead of A, B and C? In which cases is this recommendable and in which cases this is not a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can expect side effects. But it will depend on the algorithm you feed the data to. Somehow, your compression is loss-free and there exist a (non linear) mapping between (A,B,C) and X. As the mapping is non linear, some methods might recover it, others may not.

A **decision tree** might (theoretically) produce the exact same output with both encoding. Indeed `if(X>0)` is equivalent to `if(A==1)`, `if(X)>3.5` is equivalent to `if(B>3 and C>0.5)`...

On the other hand, you **enforce an order on the values of your predictor** that may not be relevant (and that was not here in the first place). It could harm performance in the case of a **linear regression**.

Besides, the metric on your input space is totally different now. Say $x_1=(1,3,0.3),x_2=(0,3,0.3)$. The distance in the original space is 1 and 6.6 in the mapped space. Likewise, you can show that some pairs will look closer in a space and not in the other. This will certainly affect **kernelized methods, KNN**...

> It seems this seems like a good idea to reduce the number of
>   dimensions of the space

It depends on how you do it. Linear dimension reduction methods (like  **PCA** or **Random Projection**) usually provide good results. There are plenty of non linear methods as well. But not every dimension reduction is fruitful.

You could map $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$ (even $\mathbb{R^n}$) considering the alternating sequence of decimals of each number. This would turn any $n$ dimensional data set into a one dimensional dataset. However, it is highly unlikely that you will get better performance with such a representation of the data.